# platform_device_register and usb ehci driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to understand how linux initializes USB EHCI controller on my cambria (ARM) board.

There is some file in linux kernel:

```
arch/arm/mach-ixp4xx/cambria-setup.c
```

and there is some definition of USB EHCI controller as platform device:

```
static struct platform_device cambria_usb0_device =  {
    .name       = "ixp4xx-ehci",
    .id     = 0,
    .resource   = cambria_usb0_resources,
    .num_resources  = ARRAY_SIZE(cambria_usb0_resources),
    .dev = {
        .dma_mask       = &ehci_dma_mask,
        .coherent_dma_mask  = 0xffffffff,
    },
};
```

and referenced by:

```
platform_device_register(&cambria_usb0_device);
```

My question is: how linux knows that this platform device is USB EHCI controller and should initialize ehci-hcd.ko module for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It knows because you've told it that the platform device is a USB EHCI controller :)

In the following code, you tell the kernel that the name of the peripheral is "ixp4xx-ehci".

```
    .name       = "ixp4xx-ehci",
```

The kernel will search for a driver that can handle this kind of hardware some time after you register it. Whatever driver (in your case, the ehci-hcd module) matches the peripheral name will be attached to that device.

Comment: A few minutes after I asked the question I found the answer by myself :) It is role of ehci-ixp4xx.c file to find "ixp4xx-ehci" name and configure ehci. Of course your answer is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information for the question.
Linux device driver model reveal the underlaying relations. There are several good book to help you understand more regarding linux device driver.
Platform device and driver are both register to platform bus, when driver is registered, the bus driver will try to match the match them (via name here) and probe the device then.